# Robust regularized regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, predictive-models, regularization, robust

I've been using elastic net implemented in R (via glmnet) for some modeling, but I was wondering, due to the number of outliers in my data, if there was some sort of modeling approach for regularized robust regression? e.g. something like elastic net applied to robust regression. if there's something already in R, even better. Just curious to know what's out there.

Comment: Have a look at the answers to [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/214617/603) similar questions.

Comment: On the basis of this article https://towardsdatascience.com/penalized-regressions-with-jmp-e10628799aef (A "Towards Data Science Article", mind you, not a journal article), there seems to be an implementation of Lasso-penalized Cauchy regression in JMP. I don't have access to that software to confirm this.

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be some relevant papers. You can start with:

[Robust regression through the Huber’s criterion and adaptive lasso penalty, Sophie Lambert-Lacroix, Laurent Zwald](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-journal-of-statistics/volume-5/issue-none/Robust-regression-through-the-Hubers-criterion-and-adaptive-lasso-penalty/10.1214/11-EJS635.full)

[Robust Regression and Lasso: Huan Xu, Constantine Caramanis, Shie Mannor (arXiv)](http://arxiv.org/abs/0811.1790)

[Sparse least trimmed squares regression for analyzing high-dimensional large data sets: Andreas Alfons, Christophe Croux, Sarah Gelper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4773)

... but I don't know about implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose we are using L1 norm on error term, the objective is still convex.

The objective is

$$\|Ax-b\|_1+\lambda_2\|x\|^2_2+\lambda_1\|x\|_1$$

Gradient is

$$A^T \text{sign}(Ax-b)+2\lambda_2x+\lambda_1 \text{sign}(x)$$

Here is a R implementation

```
f<-function(x,A,b,l1,l2){
  e=A %*% x - b
  # v=crossprod(e)+l2*crossprod(x)+l1*sum(abs(x))
  v=sum(abs(e))+l2*crossprod(x)+l1*sum(abs(x))
  return(c(v))
}

gr<-function(x,A,b,l1,l2){
  v=t(A) %*% sign(A %*% x -b)
  return(c(v)+2*l2*x+l1*sign(x))
}

set.seed(0)
par(cex=1.3)
n_data=20
n_feature=2

A=matrix(runif(n_data*n_feature),ncol=n_feature)
b=matrix(runif(n_data),ncol=1)

l1=0.01
l2=0.01

opt=optimx::optimx(runif(n_feature),f, gr,A=A,b=b,l1=l1,l2=l2, method="BFGS")
opt
```

Here is the results and visualization

```
> opt
            p1        p2    value fevals gevals niter convcode  kkt1 kkt2 xtimes
BFGS 0.2600659 0.7781711 4.995662    179     29    NA        0 FALSE   NA      0
```

[image]